# No lease on file (inode 5425306): File does not exist. [Lease. Holder: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-247167534_42, pendingcreates: 1]

Tags: apache-storm

I am getting below error while working with Apache storm and HDFS.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: No lease on /user/test/xxx/ccc/bbb/value_fct_archive.csv (inode 5425306): File does not exist. [Lease.  Holder: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-247167534_42, pendingcreates: 1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3521)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.analyzeFileState(FSNamesystem.java:3324)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3162)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:843)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:500)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2313)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2309)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2307)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1552) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1496) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1396) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.addBlock(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:457) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:278) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:194) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:176) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.addBlock(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1489) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1284) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:463) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
```

I tried to resolve it by many ways like increasing ulimit or setting parallelism hint to 1 etc. but nothing worked for me.

My topology code is as below,

```
public class Topology {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Topology.class);

public static StormTopology buildTopology() {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    // read properties and send to MQTT spout
    PropertyReader propReader = new PropertyReader();
    Properties prop = propReader.getProperties();
    String mqttService = (propReader.getValue(prop, "mqttservice")).trim();

    String[] devicesTopics = ((propReader.getValue(prop, "devices_topics.MQTT")).trim()).split(",");
    for(String devicesTopicsId:devicesTopics){
        LOG.info("devicesTopics Id  is "+devicesTopicsId);
        String[] devices = devicesTopicsId.split(":");
        String deviceId = devices[0];
        LOG.info("device Id  is "+deviceId);
        String mqtttopic = devices[1];
        LOG.info("Topic Name  is "+mqtttopic);
        //start topology logic
        String mqttreader="mqttreader-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("Mqtt reader  is "+mqttreader);
        String stream="stream-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("Stream Id  is "+stream);
        builder.setSpout(mqttreader, new MQTTReader(mqttService,mqtttopic,deviceId,stream));

        //set mqttprocessor bolt
        String mqttprocesser="mqttprocesser-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("Mqtt processor  is "+mqttprocesser);
        builder.setBolt(mqttprocesser, new MQTTProcesser(stream)).shuffleGrouping(mqttreader,stream);

        //set dateretriver bolt
        String dateretriver="dateretriver-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("date retriver  is "+dateretriver);
        builder.setBolt(dateretriver, new DateRetriver(stream)).shuffleGrouping(mqttprocesser,stream);

        //set archival bolt from dateretriver
        String archive="archive-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("archival  is "+archive);
        builder.setBolt(archive, new Archival(stream)).shuffleGrouping(dateretriver,stream);

        //get hive bolt
        MQTTHiveSinker sinker = new MQTTHiveSinker();
        String metaStoreURI = (propReader.getValue(prop, "hiveurl")).trim();
        String dbName = (propReader.getValue(prop, "dbname.MQTT")).trim();
        String tblName = (propReader.getValue(prop, "tblname.MQTT")).trim();
        String[] colNames = ((propReader.getValue(prop, "colNames.MQTT")).trim()).split(",");
        LOG.info("colName0  is "+colNames[0]);
        LOG.info("colName1  is "+colNames[1]);
        LOG.info("colName2  is "+colNames[2]);
        LOG.info("colName3  is "+colNames[3]);
        HiveBolt hiveBolt = sinker.buildHiveBolt(metaStoreURI, dbName, tblName, colNames);

        //set hive bolt
        String hivebolt="hivebolt-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("Hivbolt  is "+hivebolt);
        builder.setBolt(hivebolt, hiveBolt).shuffleGrouping(archive);

        //set hdfs bolt
        MQTTHDFSSinker hdfssinker = new MQTTHDFSSinker();
        String hdfsboltId="hdfsbolt-"+deviceId;
        LOG.info("hdfsbolt  is "+hdfsboltId);
        HdfsBolt hdfbolt = hdfssinker.makeHDFSBolt();
        builder.setBolt(hdfsboltId,hdfbolt).shuffleGrouping(archive);
    }   
    return builder.createTopology();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException, AuthorizationException {     
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);
    conf.setNumWorkers(2);
    //conf.setMaxSpoutPending(1);
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], conf, buildTopology());
}
```

And HDFS streaming code as below,

```
public class MQTTHDFSSinker {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQTTHDFSSinker.class);
public HdfsBolt makeHDFSBolt(){
    LOG.info("start of MQTTHDFSSinker.makeHDFSBolt");
    RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat().withFieldDelimiter(",");

    // sync the filesystem after every 1k tuples
    SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(1000);

    // rotate files when they reach 5MB
    FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(5.0f, Units.MB);

    FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new CustomHDFSFileNameFormat("/user/test/xxx/ccc/bbb/","value_fct_archive","csv");

    HdfsBolt bolt = new HdfsBolt().withFsUrl("hdfs://namenode:8020").withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat).withRecordFormat(format).withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy).withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy);
    LOG.info("end of MQTTHDFSSinker.makeHDFSBolt");
    return bolt;
}

}
```

Is it issue of multiple threads trying to write the file. Can anybody please help me for the error.

### EDIT

What I have observed that using DefaultFileNameFormat works fine for me. So can any body please tell me what should I do in my custom hdfs file name format so that it can also work without no lease file error.

```
public class CustomHDFSFileNameFormat implements FileNameFormat{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String filename=null;
private String extension=null;
private String path=null;

public CustomHDFSFileNameFormat(String path,String filename,String extension){
    this.filename = filename;
    this.extension = extension;
    this.path = path;
}
public String getName(long rotation, long timeStamp) {
    return (this.filename+"."+this.extension);
}

public String getPath() {
    return this.path;
}

public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```